# Weird node edit issue

Tags: 7, forms, users, nodes

Having spent 2 days coding my own content access module, I've managed to grant along with Organic Groups the intended set of permissions to my users.

Thing is, that authenticated users who now have edit grants on nodes, when they press the "Edit" tab, they can only edit the node's title!

Did a print_r in my form_alter for that form and it seems all form elements except for the title have their #access set to FALSE.

Any ideas on what might be going on here? I mean I can set it to TRUE in the same function but instead of repairing the problem I'd like to correct it.

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you run "Rebuild permissions" (admin/reports/status/rebuild) in "admin/reports/status"?

Comment: Yes, yes. The permissions are all ok. I even set the "Bypass content access control" thingy to test. The node/%/edit page is visitable and viewable by users with the correct permissions. It's the form's fields that are not accessible!